# iOS inapp payments - what is the right way to confirm to the user when they have made a purchase?

Tags: ios, ios6

I am confused about how to and when to tell the user that they completed the purchase successfully. I got my application rejected during the app review process for this reason:

```
1. Launch app
2. Tap on learn about the benefits of subscription
3. Tap on Subscribe
4. Tap on Confirm and enter iTunes password
5. No further action occurs
```

And I am not sure when and how to tell the user they entered their info correctly since that is confirmed on the iTunes server.

I have an IAPHelper class which looks like this:

```
//
//  IAPHelper.m
//  BusinessPlan
//
//  Created by MacOSLion on 8/12/13.
//
//

// 1
#import "IAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

// 2
//@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate>
@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
@end

@implementation IAPHelper
{
    // 3
    SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;

    // 4
    RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;
    NSSet * _productIdentifiers;
    NSMutableSet * _purchasedProductIdentifiers;
}

    - (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers
    {        
        if ((self = [super init]))
        {
            // Store product identifiers
            _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

            // Check for previously purchased products
            _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
            for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers)
            {
                BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
                if (productPurchased)
                {
                    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
                    NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);

                    // SET memory to yes and then use that later.
                    // Get user data.
                    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

                    // First time on the app, so set the user cookie.
                    [standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"subscriber"];

                    // Saving
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
                }
            }

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        }
        return self;
    }


    // retrieve the product information from iTunes Connect
    - (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler
    {    
        // 1
        _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

        // 2
        _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
        _productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [_productsRequest start];

    }

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    _completionHandler(NO, nil);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}

- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product
{    
    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    // SET memory to yes and then use that later.
    // Get user data.
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // First time on the app, so set the user cookie.
    [standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"subscriber"];

    // Saving
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    // Tell user that things are purchased.

    // MESSAGE PERSON THAT CAN'T CONNECT TO SERVER
//    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success sending purchase request."
//                                                      message:@"Just press OK and wait a few moments while iTunes processes the request." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];
//    
//    [message show];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{    
    NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);

        // MESSAGE PERSON THAT CAN'T CONNECT TO SERVER
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Could not complete your transaction"
        message:@"Please try again. If the error persists, please email support at: alex@problemio.com" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [message show];
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

// Add to top of file
NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification = @"IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification";

// Add new method
- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    //NSLog(@"Provifing content for subsciber: ");

    // MESSAGE PERSON THAT CAN'T CONNECT TO SERVER
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Subscribed successfully!"
                                                      message:@"Now you can ask questions right on the app, and get our monthly business content." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [message show];

    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];

}

@end
```

And my class from which I start the transaction process:

```
#import "SubscriptionController.h"

// 1
#import "RageIAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

// 2
@interface SubscriptionController ()
{
    NSArray *_products;

    // Add new instance variable to class extension
    NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;
}
@end

@implementation SubscriptionController

// 3
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    //[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self reload];
    //[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

    // Add to end of viewDidLoad
    _priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.859 alpha:1.000];    
}

// 4
- (void)reload
{
    _products = nil;
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            _products = products;
            //[self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        //[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// 5
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _products.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"a");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;


    // Add to bottom of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath (before return cell)
    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

    if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
        [buyButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
    }

    return cell;
}

//- (IBAction)subscribe:(id)sender
//{
//    UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
//    SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];
//    
//    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
//    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
//}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"PURCHASEDDDDDDDDD");


//    NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
//    [_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
//     {
//         if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier])
//         {
//             // TODO:
//             // Update how the button appears.
//             
//             
////             [self.table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//             *stop = YES;
//         }
//     }];

    // MESSAGE PERSON THAT CAN'T CONNECT TO SERVER
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchased successfully"
                                                      message:@":)" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [message show];

    // PUSH TO CONFIRMATION

}
//- (IBAction)subscribe:(id)sender
//{
//    
//}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


- (IBAction)createSub:(id)sender
{
        UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];


    if ( product == nil)
    {
        // MESSAGE PERSON THAT CAN'T CONNECT TO SERVER
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pulling product data from iTunes..."
                                                          message:@"Please try again in a few moments." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [message show];
    }
    else
    {
        // MESSAGE PERSON THAT CAN'T CONNECT TO SERVER
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success sending purchase request."
        message:@"Just press OK and wait a few moments while iTunes processes the request." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [message show];

        NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
        [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
    }
}
@end
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should have some sort of UI update to tell the user that the payment was successful and the feature is now available/unlocked. Typically, this is done either with an update in your views to correspond to the new content, or a `UIAlertView` if there are no visual changes made.

Comment: Yeah, @coneybeare is right. Usually for the in apps we put label with the price that's being purchased, and when payment is successful, we change that label in to purchased, or just take away the price label.